# rename multiple files in a directory

Tags: unix

I have a bunch of files in a directory. The file names are created like this: a_dc.ac.txt, a_dc.aa.txt, a_dc.cc.txt and so on. I need to replace all the a_dc portion of the names to a_adj. I tried the following but it's not working:

rename 's/a_dc/a_adj/s' *

Is there any other way to fix this? I am not sure why rename is not working.

P.S. I am using centos

Comment: If this is a one-time deal, rather than trying to do it with a single script, just copy the directory contents into a spreadsheet, and build a rename command for each one using a simple string manipulation formula, then copy the result column and paste it into the terminal.

Comment: I don't have it on me right now, but I wrote a bash script to loop through the directory using ls, split the name of the file on '.', replace the part you want to replace, rebuild the name, and rename the file.

Answer (score 3):

Using find one-liner:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'a_dc.*.txt' -exec bash -c 'x="{}"; mv "$x" "a_adj.${x#*.*.}"' \;
```

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.